# C# global/public variables that keeps value

Tags: c#, variables

I got a newbie question !

What I have is 3 windows form, named frmMain,frmSub1,frmSub2 for example.
I want a int **variable** which gets value from processes in frmSub or frmSub2 then used in frmMain for another process.

I explored other QA's before posting this. But none of them satisfied my curiosity. I just saw bunch of codes but I want a meaningful explonation with codes as why/how them works.

Many thanks for suggestions.

**Edit :**

I don't have any code for this inquiry at all. There is no application yet. I'm at planning phase. Sorry for "no code given". I can write codes after I get the stage of where I need this variable.

Comment: Please add relevant sections of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
public class frmMain
{
    public static int Vartoshare=100;


    private void setvalues()
    {
        vartoshare=200;
    }
}
```

then in your frmsub2 form you can call

```
int readvar = frmmain.vartoshare;
```

Comment: Oops! You forgot it must be `public static int Vartoshare` otherwise the other forms will not find it, as they do not have a reference to the instantied form.

Comment: Im not sure if that you are saying its true, but I added it just in case I normally use vb and learning c# in vb it would work

Comment: I'll try this as soon as possible SO what will be value of readvar ?

Comment: if you did not fire setvalues it will be 100, setvalues in an example that ilustrates how you can change the value in each from. in that case you are changing your value to 200

Comment: I tried your solution and It works. So, static is the key I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** you can pass your `int` variable to New Form `Constructor` and assign that value in the `NewForm` constructor.

Try This:

**Program.cs**

```
   static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1(0));
    }
```

**Form1 Code:**

```
    int no = 10;
    public Form1(int no)
    {
        this.no=no;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(no);
        this.Hide();
        form2.ShowDialog();            
    }
```

**Form 2: Code**

```
    int no;
    public Form2(int no)
    {
        this.no = no;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        no = 20;           
        Form1 form1 = new Form1(no);
        this.Hide();
        form1.Show();
    }
```

**Solution 2:**  you can take `public` `static` varible in `Form1` and access that variable in chid forms using their class names.

Try This:

**Form1 Code:**

```
    public static int no = 10;
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        this.Hide();
        form2.ShowDialog();            
    }
```

**Form 2: Code**

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.no = 20; //access Form1 int variable      
        Form1 form1 = new Form1(no);
        this.Hide();
        form1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I'll try this suggestions, thank you. I'll write back when I'm able to try :)

Comment: What I learnt today is, "public declaration itself not enough I guess. Static is the key of the work it seems. I've doing all wrong in my previous project. Thanks.